# i am trying to add exception handling in powershell script for azure cloud but try block is not responding when error occurs

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

```
#adding wrong parameters for checking the try block
$RGName = "RG1"
$VMName="VM1"
$VMSize="standard_B1ls"

$VirtualMachine = Get-AzVm | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -eq $RGName } | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $VMName}
$virtualMachine.HardwareProfile.VmSize = $VMSize 
#try block       
    try{
        Update-AzVM -VM $VirtualMachine -ResourceGroupName $RGname
        write-host "you are in try block "
    }
    catch{
        write-host "you are in catch block "
    }
```

catch block is not working I need to not print try block write-host is exception occurred instead of print catch write-host

Comment: Try using the -ErrorVariable parameter in Update-AzVM as well as set the -ErrorAction to "SilentlyContinue". And then on the catch block, print the error variable. Maybe this will give you something.

Comment: The code works for me, I get to the catch block. Maybe try changing `Update-AzVM -VM $VirtualMachine -ResourceGroupName $RGname` to `Update-AzVM -VM $VirtualMachine -ResourceGroupName $RGname -ErrorAction Stop` in case your $ErrorActionVariable is set to Continue for some reason.